# MPMoviePlayerController won't play when using Storyboard / Shows black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I was trying to play a video in background in my app, but it didn't work when I was using Storyboard. I read something about ARC and tried everything, but my video won't simply play. I tried the exact same thing but with another project where I deleted the Storyboard-file, and there it worked. I need to use this in my project where I'm using Storyboard. Please help me.

Here's the code:

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "AnimatedLoginViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController (){
    MPMoviePlayerController *player;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    NSURL *movieUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"background"  withExtension:@"mp4"];

    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    player.view.frame = screen;
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [self.player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player prepareToPlay];


    UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 90, 190, 40)];
    logo.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [logo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_welcome.png"]];

    [self.view addSubview:logo];


    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0];
    UIFont *defaultFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0];


    NSDictionary * attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor whiteColor], defaultFont, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    NSDictionary * attributesBold = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor whiteColor], boldFont, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor blackColor], defaultFont, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    attributesBold = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor blackColor], boldFont, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    UIButton *emailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [emailButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, screen.size.height==568?455:370, 300, 43)];

    attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Enter your work " attributes:attributes]];

    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Email" attributes:attributesBold]];
    [emailButton setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [emailButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SignInMailButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [emailButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SignInMailButtonTap.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [emailButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SignInMailButtonTap.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [emailButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:emailButton];


    boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0];
    defaultFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0];

    attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor grayColor], defaultFont, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    attributesBold = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor whiteColor], boldFont, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    UIButton *signInButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [signInButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, screen.size.height==568?500:410, 300, 43)];

    attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Do you have an activation code? " attributes:attributes]];

    [attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Enter now" attributes:attributesBold]];
    [signInButton setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [signInButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:signInButton];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playVideo)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification
                                               object:player];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.player];

    [player play];
}

- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (note.object == self.player) {
        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
        {
            [self.player play];
        }
    }
}

-(void)playVideo{
    [player play];
}

@end
```

Comment: What controllers do you have in your storyboard? Do you see the movie player, but it doesn't play?

Comment: I'm not using any controllers. I'm using this library, check it out: https://github.com/arturfelipet/AnimatedLogin

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about view controllers. Obviously, you have at least one of them.

Comment: It sounds to me like you might have more than one view controller, and you're seeing the one that's not in the storyboard. Do you have the same code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (in the app delegate), that's in the library you linked to?